# Section with modals stretching out the row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a section with three image modals in it. The button to open the modals are photos. My question is, why are the three image buttons stretched across the screen? What happened to the auto margin on the sides of the row that bootstrap always puts in? Its like the row is stretched out. Here is my HTML

```
<section class="section2">
    <div class"container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 section2Text">
                <h2 class="text-center">Stock Footage</h2>
                <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam non nunc nec enim fringilla convallis at et neque. Maecenas vitae tortor porttitor, sollicitudin lorem nec, cursus est. Mauris vel ligula ac sapien pulvinar tempor. Nullam rutrum finibus nisl, sed euismod mi placerat id.</p>
            </div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog mDialogPhoto" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsiveModal" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/mainPhoto1LG.jpg'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog mDialogPhoto" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsiveModal" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/mainPhoto2LG.jpg'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog mDialogPhoto" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsiveModal" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/mainPhoto3LG.jpg'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4 photoBG">
                        <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/photoImage1-1.jpg'/></a>
                        <p class="text-center"><span>Compass Cay</span><br></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4 photoBG">
                        <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/photoImage2-1.jpg'/></a>
                         <p class="text-center"><span>Whiteside</span><br></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4 photoBG">
                        <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/photoImage3-1.jpg'/></a>
                        <p class="text-center"><span>Exuma Rocks</span><br></p>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                            <a class="btn contentBtn btn-block" href="/videography#photography">View Photos</a>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 visible-xs visible-sm">
                            <a class="btn contentBtn btn-block" href="/videography#photography">View Photos</a>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and CSS

```
.mDialogPhoto {
        width: 95%;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .modal-body {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .modal-backdrop.in {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    .modal-content {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .img-responsiveModal {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .modal-dialog {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    .photoBG span {
        font-size: 2em;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    .photoBG p {
        background-color: #e2e3df;
        font-size: .8em;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-bottom: 13px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you missed the equals sign in `<div class="container">`.

Adding this in corrects the issue (click 'Full page' to see this in effect):

```css
.mDialogPhoto {
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 0px;
}

.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.img-responsiveModal {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.modal-dialog {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.photoBG span {
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.photoBG p {
  background-color: #e2e3df;
  font-size: .8em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="section2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 section2Text">
        <h2 class="text-center">Stock Footage</h2>
        <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam non nunc nec enim fringilla convallis at et neque. Maecenas vitae tortor porttitor, sollicitudin lorem nec, cursus est. Mauris vel ligula ac sapien pulvinar tempor. Nullam rutrum
          finibus nisl, sed euismod mi placerat id.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog mDialogPhoto" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <img class="img-responsiveModal" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/mainPhoto1LG.jpg' />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog mDialogPhoto" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <img class="img-responsiveModal" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/mainPhoto2LG.jpg' />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog mDialogPhoto" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <img class="img-responsiveModal" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/mainPhoto3LG.jpg' />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4 photoBG">
        <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/photoImage1-1.jpg' /></a>
        <p class="text-center"><span>Compass Cay</span><br></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4 photoBG">
        <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/photoImage2-1.jpg' /></a>
        <p class="text-center"><span>Whiteside</span><br></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4 photoBG">
        <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/photoImage3-1.jpg' /></a>
        <p class="text-center"><span>Exuma Rocks</span><br></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <a class="btn contentBtn btn-block" href="/videography#photography">View Photos</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 visible-xs visible-sm">
        <a class="btn contentBtn btn-block" href="/videography#photography">View Photos</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps! :)